# Large Accented Button in SwiftUI macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, macos-big-sur

How can I create a button like the following in SwiftUI in macOS?

[image]

Edit: Here is the code I am using to create the button:

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
  VStack {
    Text("Sign In")
  }
}
.buttonStyle(.bordered)
```

This produces:

[image]

However, attempting to add padding within the button creates this issue:

[image]

A similar issue arises when using `frame(width:height:)` on the button, or on the content within the button.

Additionally, how can I accent this button, just like in the Pages onboarding?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You put a background with a rounded rectangle on it, filled with whatever color you want. I am not sure what you mean by accent, other than the background color. If you want to change the text color on a button, you change the foreground color. Without posted code, there is not much more in answer to this.

Comment: @Yrb Thank you for the quick response: I am looking for the Apple system button, not a custom button. I've added some code to the original question to help clarify.

Comment: SwiftUI does not work that way. This isn't UIKit where you drag in a UIButton and set your attributes. A basic SwiftUI is simply text in a different color. Everything else you see IS custom. In this case, your button has to be custom, and not use` Button()` at all. This is what a declarative interface is about.

Comment: Yeah just make your own custom button, including the gradient, border, padding, etc. Use `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` to get rid of all the default traits.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm still new to SwiftUI on macOS. I'll be sure to use that! @Yrb

Comment: All of these other responders are just ignoring that fact that Apple's rounded buttons are textured. The fact is that Apple doesn't make taller textures available to us. If you want a button that looks just like Apple's, textures and all, you're going to have to work very hard at reproducing it yourself.

Comment: This is a more complete answer to my question. Thanks @robmayoff !

Answer (score 1):

you could try something simple like this:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Sign In")
        .padding(22)
        .frame(width: 222, height: 44)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
}.frame(width: 222, height: 44)
 .background(Color.blue).cornerRadius(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Color.gray
            .frame(width: 800.0, height: 500.0)
            .overlay(CustomButtonView().padding(), alignment: .bottom)
            
        
    }
    
}


struct CustomButtonView: View {
    
    @State private var scaleAnimation: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Button").frame(width: 300.0, height: 50.0).background(Color.blue.cornerRadius(10)).foregroundColor(.white).onTapGesture {
            print("Action!")
            scaleAnimation = true
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(100)) { scaleAnimation = false }
            
        }
        .shadow(radius: 5)
        .scaleEffect(scaleAnimation ? 0.98 : 1.0)
        .animation(.interactiveSpring(), value: scaleAnimation)
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]